# Change of Server (IP Address) Affects Access to the server from Domain SSL Certificated by LetsEncrypt

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, lets-encrypt

According to many answers the Certificate is not bound to the IP address but bound to the domain. But still I can not reach the application by using the domain. Is there a way to notify the DNS that the IP has changed.

When I try to renew the certificate,

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -w /etc/apache2/ssl/ -d mkt.example.com
```

I get to select

How would you like to authenticate with ACME CA?
I selected apache, But I get the following error,

```
 No vhost exists with servername or alias of: mkt.example.com. 
 No vhost was selected. Please specify servernames in the Apache config
```

With the following detail.

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:

   - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: mkt.example.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Failed to connect to 53.90.140.146:443 for TLS-SNI-01
   challenge

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

Here, the previous IP address is 53.90.140.146. But the new IP is a different one.

So how should I resolve this issue

Comment: Have you in fact updated the address in your public DNS?  If so, how long ago, and what's the TTL on the record?

Comment: Did you have RDNS set up for the IP also?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you didn't obscure the domain name, by the way.

Comment: @MadHatter I have not done any of that, I just used lets encrypt to create the certificate  and key and use that in my apache vritual host configuration. How can I update the public DNS. I am on a AWS instance

Comment: @NickW what ever the letsencrypt is supporting. I am not responsible of any of these.

Comment: If you have not changed the DNS, *nothing in this question makes any sense*.  Are you saying you've migrated your server to an AWS VPS (possibly from another AWS VPS) and you just want to know how to put the new IP into your DNS?  Your answer to NickW's question above is making me very nervous that this isn't your core field of expertise, to put it mildly.

Comment: @MadHatter that's why he or she is asking here, to put it mildly...

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky that doesn't make the question on-topic.